# Do I need driver for a network printer?

Tags: printing

I think I shouldn't need a driver for a network printer, other than a software help scanning the printer IP on the network; as long as I know the IP, then all printer should share the same interface. Is that correct?

*Edit*: I'm having an EziPrinter

Comment: It would help if you mentioned which kind of printer it is!

Answer (score 0):

You generally need a PPD, Ubuntu 12.04 has a nice printer interface and will find network printers, it will then try to find an appropriate PPD, if it fails then try the manufactures website they may supply it. Else as a last resort you can try a PPD meant for a similar printer as it may work.

OKay because ubuntu does not identify your printer then your only hope other than getting the appropiate ppd off the printer manufacturer is to add a printer using the printer wizard, Most network printers accept print jobs on port 9100, so choose the AppSocket/HP JetDirect protocol, enter you printers IP, and hit next.

[image]

Then choose a really generic printer HP LaserJet4 if its there and see if it works

Comment: I have a LAN EziPrinter. It bundled with a Windows driver CD. But the CD contains an MSI file to install driver, and I'm unable to find the PPD file accompanied with it.

Comment: Does that mean every machine that need to print something with the printer will need that PPD file?

Comment: Sorry I have never heard of that Brand, Every linux machine will need the ppd..  However if you got to the printers manufacturer website they may supply the appropriate PPD, have you tried using the printer wizard in ubuntu?

Comment: I used the printer wizard but Ubuntu won't identify such printer

Comment: Is there a way to locate the ppd file from a Windows XP machine (which the driver of the file installed)

Comment: If I switch over to an Epson TM-T81, where can I get the PPD file?

Comment: If its not in the print wizard then from Epson.